# When does The Banner Saga save?

Tags: the-banner-saga

From the looks of it, there's no way to manually save — no problem, since the people who made the game prolly wanted to make the choices feel meaningful, and not something you go back and forth on...

However, there's also no indication that the game has autosaved at any point — which means I've sometimes made choices, gone through dialogues, thought that was a good place to quit... only to relaunch the game, hit resume, and find myself having to go through pieces of dialogue I'd already gone through.

Dunno if it saves before fights, when you camp, when you reach towns/villages, when you make any sort of choice... So, yeah: **when does the game autosave, exactly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this thread on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bannersaga/comments/6ofdun/very_upset_with_banner_saga_1_right_now_when_is/)

> the game saves anytime you quit to the main menu while not in combat or conversation. It also saves at chapter changes and while resting in camp

and

> the game autosaves whenever you are in closer-travel mode (side-view of the caravan, with small sprites, e.g. Camp/Village/Town/Godstone)(world-travel mode is also a side-view of the caravan, but sprites are tiny) and in a few other specific locations.
>
> In the case of Chapter 3, the game will surely autosave when you reach the Tower, but I'm not sure if there's other save locations. This means that you'll probably have to go through all the Ridgehorn battles in-a-row.

and according to this steam [thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/237990/discussions/0/1291816569122539469/)

> the game autosaves on checkpoints. The game also generates a single "Resume" save-lost when you quit anytime during a so-called close travel scene, e.g. when in Camp or in a town/village/godstone. It does not save if you quit in the middle of a battle or a dialogue.

Further info on saving that occurs during checkpoints can be found [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/237990/discussions/0/558752451293786483/#c558752451323349067)

> The game auto-saves everytime you go into Camp, or into a Village/Town where there's a building to click on (e.g. Rest, Market, Leave etc).
>
> Apart from that "active" save-slot, there's also several save-slots automatically generated each time you meet an important story-checkpoint (e.g. a major city, a godstone, a chapter-start etc). Those "checkpoint" save-slots are overwritten each time you visit the specific locaton anew (e.g. on a next playthrough), and you can reload them anytime you like.

Comment: Ok, so basically it saves whenever I go into "close travel scene?" There's a mention of checkpoints there, but similarly to autosaves, there are no indications that we've reached these — which is to say, my question could just as easily be read as "what are considered checkpoints in the game?"

Comment: @JNat https://steamcommunity.com/app/237990/discussions/0/558752451293786483/#c558752451323349067